# How to obtain properties from an array of objects in javascript/ nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of objects as such:

```
const objArray = [{prop: "a", prop2 : "1"}, {prop: "b", prop2 : "2"}, {prop: "c"}, prop2 : "3"]
```

How do I extract the property name of the array of objects (not the values of the property).

Outcome :

```
["prop", "prop2"]
```

Context: I wanna create a function to just get the properties of an object whenever I pass in any array of objects.
I'm using ES6 syntax.

Comment: How would you do it, if it wasn't in an array, and you just had an object? Also, your array is invalid syntax, the third (or fourth?) object has awkward braces

Comment: hint: use Object.keys

Comment: @ASDFGerte : oops yea, i was copying it in a rush. Here's the correct one:

const objArray = [{prop: "a", prop2 : "1"}, {prop: "b", prop2 : "2"}, {prop: "c", prop2 : "3"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Object.keys() method to retrieve "KEYS" from JavaScript Object. Below is the code for retrieving "Keys" from your object.

```
const objArray = [
  { prop: "a", prop2: "1" },
  { prop: "b", prop2: "2" },
  { prop: "c", prop2: "3" }
];

const resArray = objArray.map(e => {
  return Object.keys(e);
});

console.log(resArray);
```

Comment: @Syabster, this is not the outcome you have mentioned in your question!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use map() to iterate over the objects of an array. To get all the keys you can use Object.keys() which returns all the keys in an Object.

Full documentation is available on the MDN site linked below:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

```
const objArray = [
  { prop: "a", prop2: "1" },
  { prop: "b", prop2: "2" },
  { prop: "c", prop2: "3" }
];

let keysArray = objArray.map(e => Object.keys(e));

console.log("keysArray ---", keysArray);
```

**Output:**

```
keysArray --- [ [ 'prop', 'prop2' ], [ 'prop', 'prop2' ], [ 'prop', 'prop2' ] ]
```